# How to query exact match of a string on any field in Elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-1.7.5

We have a use case that require us to fetch all records that has an exact match on any field value. E.g. check if any of the below field has a exact string value as "auto-scaling-groups"

```
Record 1: { "name": "auto-scaling-groups", "created_by": "John" }
Record 2: { "name": "postgres-db-node", "managed_by": "auto-scaling-groups" }
Record 3: { "name": "postgres-db-cluster", "managed_by": "auto-scaling-groups-manager"}
Record 4: { "name": "postgres-db-monitoring", "managed_by": "auto-scaling-scheduler"}
```

The query result should only return records 1 and 2 but not 3 and 4.

Please note that we have ES cluster v1.7 and do not have luxury of using latest features such as `keyword` analyzer as below.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "auto-scaling-groups",
            "analyzer": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a keyword field for your **text fields** on which you need to search, ie `name`, `created_by` and `managed_by` than It would be difficult to achieve your use-case, what you can do is create a `keyword` data type for all these fields and than you can use the `term` query on search on the keyword fields to get the exact match.

Comment: can you share the term query that search exact match on any field? I though the term query should be on a specific field?

Comment: Also, I tried to create keyword for all these fields but ES 1.7 did not allow so thats not an option.

Comment: @Azura are you still facing issue?